# Representing numbers with IEEE 754 in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I would like to write a C++ program to represent numbers with IEEE 754 Standard for Floating Point, without any supplementary dictionaries. Is that possible? Thank you!

Comment: On 99% of architectures use `float` or `double`. See [Floating-point types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) (scroll down a bit).

Comment: Most implementations (and all common ones...) do use IEE754 for floating point numbers. What do you want exactly?

Comment: What you are asking is too general. If this is for a course and you have to write your own IEEE 754 support, the best advice I can give is to read the IEEE 754 spec, write the code, and come back later if you run into a specific problem.

Comment: Basically a program where I input a real number and get it converted in "32 Bits Single Precision IEEE 754 Floating Point Representation". With sign, exponent, mantissa, if you understand.

Comment: So on Windows or Linux with a mainstream compiler just use `float`.

Comment: That I understand. If you can guarantee the target system uses IEEE 754, a near-certainty these days, you can read the number from the user into a `float` and then use the common bit-masking techniques you should already know to isolate the bits of interest and print them. If you do not know basic bit-masking, that should be the main thrust of your question. If you cannot guarantee that the target operates on IEEE 754, you're back to my earlier suggestion: read the spec, write the code, ask targeted questions as needed.

Comment: Just check whether `std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559` is true or false. IEC 559 is equivalent to IEEE 754, so if the value is true for your unspecified platform, you're in the clear. If it's false, you have a lot of work to do.

Answer (score 1):

> ... represent numbers with IEEE 754 Standard for Floating Point ...

Either your implementation already uses this for `float` (single-precision) and `double` (double-precision), or it doesn't. You haven't told us what implementation you're using, so we can't tell you.

You can, however, just check whether [`std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559) is `true` or `false` on your mystery platform.

IEC 559 is equivalent to IEEE 754, so if the value is true, you're in the clear. If it's false, you have a lot of work to do